# How to use res folder instead sdcard

Tags: java, android

I have some files on sd card, but i want put them in apk file, to res/raw folder, how i should change string to use that folder?

```
f = new File("/sdcard/file.ext");
```

Comment: `... to res/images folder` consider using `/res/raw/` or `/assets/images/` folder, since `/res/images/` is not an accessible folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the resource by the following code.

```
lytImage.setBackgroundResource(mContext.getResources()
                .getIdentifier("ImageName", "drawable", "application package name"));
```